# ManyToMany. Spring. Possible to update list of (B) data in table A, by only saving table B(managing side)

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

So, I have two tables, a Group and a Person table. They have a many to many relationship. Group have a collection of Persons and Person got a collection of Groups. Group is set as managing part of the relationship. My question is, is it possible for me to create a new Person, without a group, then create a new Group, add that newly created Person, then save that group, and as a result have that the new Person is related to the new group if for example "getGroups()" is called?

My classes:
Group, Person

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = Group.TABLE_NAME)
public class Group {

static final String TABLE_NAME = "GROUP";

@Id
@Column(name = "GROUP_ID", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "GroupGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name="GroupGenerator", sequenceName = "GROUP_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 100)
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "GROUP_PERSON",
        joinColumns =  @JoinColumn(name = "GROUP_ID", referencedColumnName = "GROUP_ID"),
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name="PERSON_ID", referencedColumnName = "PERSON_ID")} )
private Set<Person> persons= new HashSet<>();

public void addPerson(Person person){
    if(!persons.contains(person)){
        persons.add(person);
    }
}
```

Person

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = Person.TABLE_NAME)
public class Person {

static final String TABLE_NAME = "PERSON";

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = SEQUENCE, generator = "personIdGenerator")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "personIdGenerator", sequenceName = "PERSON_SEQUENCE", allocationSize = 100)
@Column(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = false)
@Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
@Setter(AccessLevel.NONE)
private Long id;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "persons", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Group> groups = new HashSet<>();

public void addToGroup(Group group){
   if(!groups.contains(group)) {
       groups.add(group);
   }
}
```

Test that fails because getGroups() is empty. The repository is just standard CRUD:

```
@Test
public void testSaveGroupReflectedInPersonTable() throws Exception {
Group group1 = new Group;
Person person1 = new Person;
group1.addPerson(person1);
groupRepository.save(group1);
person1 = personRepository.findAll().get(0);
assertFalse(person1.getGroups().isEmpty);
}
```

Comment: Set both sides of the relationship and it should work: person.addToGroup(group);

Comment: Yeah, I know, but I kind of wanted to know if it was possible, or even recommended/not recommended to just update the managing part of the relationship, to update both tables. If I add "person.addToGroup(group)" then i works, but i wondered if it was possible to do it without calling that function.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? Your in-memory model is broken regardless of what may or may not happen on save. group.hasPerson(person) == true : person.isInGroup(group) == false **<<< bad** You should encapsulate the maintenance of this bi-directional relationship in your addXXX() methods.

Comment: I just wondered if it was the wrong way of doing things or not. And if it was even possible. 
The motivation for doing this was that then I would only have to call save for the Group table and not think about that I have to add it to the group from the Person side also.